# submit a form, but could not get input values

Tags: php, html, forms, materialize

I am facing to problems with my code

1. I am using materialize to create this webpage, but the button type  submit doesn't do anything while the input type submit run the PHP function
2. after filling the inputs and pressing the input type submit it runs the PHP code and prints "PHP function is executed" which means my variables are set to "" not to their input values

Could any one help me please

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML> 
   <html>
    <head>
        <title>Mobile Phone</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initil-scale=1.0">
        <link href="css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body class="green lighten-5"> 

        <?php
            // define variables and set to empty values
            $MID = $MModel = $Color = $Price ="";

            if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
            {
               $MID = test_input($_POST["MID"]);
               $MModel = test_input($_POST["MModel"]);
               $Color = test_input($_POST["Color"]);
                $Price = test_input($_POST["Price"]);
            }

            function test_input($data)
            {
               $data = trim($data);
               $data = stripslashes($data);
               $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
               return $data;
            }
        ?>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>

        <div class="container">   
          <div class="row">
            <form class="col s12" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s2">
                  <input placeholder="A11" id="MID" type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{2}" class="validate">
                  <label for="MID">Mobile ID</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s2">
                  <input id="MModel" type="text" class="validate">
                  <label for="MModel">Mobile Model</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s2">
                  <input id="Color" type="text" class="validate">
                  <label for="Color">Color</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s2">
                  <input id="Price" type="number" class="validate" min="0" max="5000">
                  <label for="Price">Price</label>
                </div>
                </div>

                 <!-- This do not works -->
                <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn" type="submit" name="action">Add
                    <i class="mdi-content-send right"></i>
                </button>

                <!-- This works -->
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
            </form>
                      </div>
                    </div>
        <?php
       if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
           echo "PHP function is executed<br>";
           echo $MID;
           echo $MModel;
           echo $Color;
           echo $Price;
    }
        ?>        

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: **A:** - Your POST arrays are out of scope and your inputs have no name attributes, only your submit does. So, only this will pop up `echo "PHP function is executed<br>";` while clicking on the submit button.

Comment: To prove this ^ - Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, where you will see many Undefined index... notices, then refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index on how to solve it yourself. No better way to do this, then "teach a person HOW to fish..." ;-)

Comment: Once you've managed to fix that using my comments above, you can then delete the question. If you're still having a hard time, let us know.

Comment: Thanks Fred it works now. it was missing a name attribute

Comment: You're welcome, glad to it hear it, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<button class="waves-effect waves-light btn" type="submit" name="action">Add
   <i class="mdi-content-send right"></i>
</button>
```

to

```
<button class="waves-effect waves-light btn" type="submit" name="submit">Add       
   <i class="mdi-content-send right"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer